# Refactor .Net code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, project-management, directory

After considering folder structure for Unit Testing, we like the default location inside the Project folder.  However, we have most of our projects already created w/o the extra folder inside a folder designation.  I just did the first project by manually creating a folder, changing the solution file and moving files.  Is there an easy way to remap all of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) that does that - Visual Studio can be automated using VBA, like most of MS Office.

Record the actions to create the new folder, adding to solution etc, then open the recorded macro as a starting point.

Once the macro is ready you can map a button to run it and use that for every project/solution that you need the new structure in.

Comment: I ended up doing this manually.  I wanted to have the "moves" done in TFS (and all the references were broke).  Our source tree isn't too big yet (30 projects), but still took quite awhile.  I'm happy with it now and ready to add UnitTesting.  Thanks for the idea though!